# Specifying extra XML for gradle-generated AndroidManifest

Tags: android, google-maps, testing, gradle

Is it possible to specify extra XML fields for gradle-generated AndroidManifest. The use case, specifically, is that I have an app that uses google maps, and according to [their documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#installing_the_google_maps_android_v2_api), the app must specify:

```
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>
```

in the AndroidManifest. If you then try to test this app with gradle, you'll get:

```
$ ./gradlew connectedCheck
<snip>
:myapp:processTestTestManifest
[manifestMerge1694110764542760523.xml:1, manifestMerge678902239503841223.xml:15] Main manifest has <uses-feature android:glEsVersion='0x00010000'> but library uses glEsVersion='0x00020000'
Note: main manifest lacks a <uses-feature android:glEsVersion> declaration, and thus defaults to glEsVersion=0x00010000.
```

My current (relevant) project structure is:

```
myapp/AndroidManifest.xml
myapp/project.properties
myapp/res/
myapp/src/com/magic/package/Foo.java
myapp/tests/java/com/magic/package/test/FooTest.java
```

In other words, the legacy project structure except for `tests/`. I've also tried with adding an arbitrary AndroidManifest.xml to `myapp/tests/`, even though [the doc](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Basics-and-Configuration) says not to, just as a test. However, I had no luck.

My `buid.gradle` looks like:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile project('stuff')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}
```

If I remove the `uses-feature`, the tests will run, but I'd like to avoid that, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to provide custom attribute but it looks like the merge is broken. I'll have to look into it.

**Updated:** Per [google bug filed for this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57526), this has been fixed via the new manifest merger. And from [manifest merger user guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger)

> This new merger was introduced in version 0.10 of the plugin. As of 0.11, this tool is used by default by the gradle plugin.

Comment: Should I file a bug somewhere to track this?

Comment: Please do, here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry?template=Tools%20bug%20report

Comment: this also seems to be a problem with flavors: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57526